# EXT4-fs (sda2): I/0 error while writing superblock

Tags: crash

I had installed last version of Ubuntu Budgie, and when I try to use it, the screen do this:

[crash details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSvTz.jpg)

I don't know how to fix it, any comment will be apreciatte.

Comment: I see IO errors, ie. stop trying to use it, boot a *live* system (such as your Ubuntu Budgie install media) and validate the health of your hardware.  You may have a dying, near-dead, or just sick disk (sda) that needs replacing...  Once you know the health, you can decide on a course of action (be it getting any data you don't have safely backed up before drive is dead, or starting repair..)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  (*the error is mostly just repeated, so it maybe just a bad area of the disk you can work around.. but either way access safely and not via use*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Boot a live system (Your Ubuntu Budgie install media)

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda2
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
```

Comment: **DANGER** Using the -c parameter without using -k will wipe out the pre-exisiting entries in the bad block table. Don't do it. It might not even be a good idea to try and bad block a disk that has a problem. Better to just `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2` and repair the broken file system first.

Comment: @heynnema: Corrected, according to your warning.